# How to disable reporting of SQL errors by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have my own PHP data class that records MySQL errors to a txt file using `mysqli_error($this->conn)`

Everything was working fine until I set PHP error handling to E_ALL. Now PHP intercepts the error and it doesn't get a chanced to be handled by my MySQL error handler.

This wouldn't be a problem except that PHP doesn't record the full SQL string that errored. It merely logs the first 20 characters or so followed by "..." which is not very useful for debugging.

So my question is: Is it possible to tell PHP to leave MySQL errors alone while still handling PHP errors?

I have looked at the various levels of error_reporting() but there doesn't appear to be anything that specifically leaves MySQL errors alone.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to log the SQL - *it is already in the source code* in the full glory.

Comment: The MySQL strings are dynamic 99% of the time, so they are not in the code.

Comment: It cannot be. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?` is always the same, no matter what

Comment: Although I'm not necessarily saying it is a good idea, you could pin your mysqli variable to a global area somehow, register a PHP error/exception handler, detect the error type inside to see if it is your special case and handle it then.

Comment: mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF) is a setting you are looking for, but you should really make error reporting centralized and uniform, as opposed to having each module handle errors differently

Comment: "*MySQL strings are dynamic 99% of the time*" Then you don't need to debug the SQL string but the code that incorrectly generated it. Add some unit tests to cover the logic extensively. In this regard, the SQL exception is not different from any other PHP error.

Comment: Thank you. I'll investigate mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF)
While it's true that some queries are as simple as SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? most are not. It's more like "UPDATE ". $table ." SET ".  $field ." = '". $value ."' WHERE id = ". $id

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by disabling mysqli error reporting, but any regular project should never do that. In fact, it seems you are approaching this problem from the wrong way! You should not want to disable error reporting, you should fix the errors!

As you mentioned, if the error comes from an incorrectly built dynamic SQL statement, then your code shouldn't contain any logic to handle this possible scenario, because you don't want to make bugs part of your design. It's a bug in your PHP code just like any other bug. The fact that it manifests itself as a MySQL error is irrelevant. You must fix the code that builds the invalid SQL statement! **Silencing errors does not help in fixing them!**

Assuming that your PHP code builds the SQL from constant SQL parts (if it uses variables then you have a lot bigger issue in your code) then your task is to identify which code path leads to incorrect combination of SQL keywords. You can figure it our partially from the SQL error. The exception message will tell you what the syntax error is. If the MySQL error is not related to broken syntax, then the process is still similar: find what caused the error and fix it.

Do not write special error-handling logic around your SQL code. This is messy and absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: I never mentioned silencing errors - my whole question surrounds logging errors so that they cane be fixed! The reason I record my error reporting the way I do is for ease of access. There is a module in my application where I can manage errors from all of the application interfaces both public and internal.

Comment: @MichaelLegg To log errors you can use PHP's ini directive `log_errors`. You don't need any special code in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to a use Try Catch block around the execution of the SQL string and log the error in the Catch portion of the block. This way I can log all of the details that I require including the complete SQL string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).